# corona Images in Front of cloud?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Hi for some reason i can't get **local helicopter = display.newImage("helicopter.png")**  to display in front of the clouds(moving background), is there a good way to solve this problem ?

```
<code>
function initcloud()
    local cloud1 = {}
    cloud1.imgpath = "cloud1.png"; --Set Image Path for cloud
    cloud1.movementSpeed = 10000; --Determines the movement speed of cloud
    table.insert(cloudTable, cloud1); --Insert cloud into cloudTable

    local cloud2 = {}
    cloud2.imgpath = "cloud2.png";
    cloud2.movementSpeed = 12000;
    table.insert(cloudTable, cloud2);               

    local cloud3 = {}
    cloud3.imgpath = "cloud3.png";
    cloud3.movementSpeed = 14000;
    table.insert(cloudTable, cloud3);
end --END initcloud()   

function getRandomcloud()
local temp = cloudTable[math.random(1, #cloudTable)] -- Get a random cloud from cloudTable
local randomcloud = display.newImage(temp.imgpath); --physics.addBody(randomcloud, {isSensor = true});
randomcloud.myName = "cloud";
randomcloud.movementSpeed = temp.movementSpeed; -- set the cloud cloudting point
randomcloud.x = math.random(10, _W);
randomcloud.y = -35;
randomcloud.rotation = math.random(0, 20); -- move the cloud
cloudMove = transition.to(randomcloud, {
time = randomcloud.movementSpeed, 
y = 500,
onComplete = function(self)
self.parent:remove(self);
self = nil;
end 
});
end

function cloudtGame()
    cloudTimer1 = timer.performWithDelay(1400,getRandomcloud, 0)
    cloudTimer2 = timer.performWithDelay(2000,getRandomcloud, 0)
    cloudTimer3 = timer.performWithDelay(2400,getRandomcloud, 0)        
end--END cloudtGame()

initcloud()
cloudtGame()

local helicopter = display.newImage("helicopter.png")
</code>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I ran your code with my solution, it worked. All I added was:

```
randomcloud:toBack()
```

since `randomcloud` is a display object, I can send it to the back of the page.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would by to use two DisplayGroups (one for a cloud and one for a helicopter) fitted inside one "root" group in the desired order. That way you would have only one object without a group - the "root".

http://www.coronalabs.com/blog/2012/02/28/corona-display-groups-101/